# Ensure a given module (set) is enabled on a dev site

Tags: 7, staging

Configuring dev-site specific settings is easy using the `$conf` array in `settings.php`

Sometimes I need to also disable (securepages) or enable (devel) certain modules on a dev site, but I don't know of an analogous method for doing this via `settings.php`

One hack which seems tempting is to define, say, `menu_init()` in settings.php (*gasp), and make that function check that the required modules are enabled using module_exists().

[* Yes, all manner of things might asplode if menu.module defined that function. OMG,ETC.]

So I'm wondering if people have done similar things to make sure their dev site is correctly configured, and if so, what. Is this the Poor Dev's Pantheon?

Comment: Related, but not the same question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/is-there-a-easier-way-to-disable-and-enable-module-for-module-development

Comment: Current approach is to make a little restore.sh which installs the DB, makes any DB-level changes required, and then calls drush to enable/disable the modules required.

Comment: We use a [custom drush command](http://www.thirdandgrove.com/blog/2013/08/custom-drush-command.html) for this.

Comment: Tonight I noticed [Environment Modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/environment_modules) which appears to be another (see answer below) solution  to part of this. Not a recommendation, just noticed it exists.

Answer (score 5):

(It was me who wrote the instructions for the `hook_init()` hack at http://drupal.org/node/206368.)

Recent module-level ways of supporting this workflow are underway at the [Environment](http://drupal.org/project/environment) module, and the [Production check & Production monitor](http://drupal.org/project/prod_check).

I feel they will rapidly become too bulky: Do you really need to enable a module to ensure another module is turned off? 
But, at least they may be able to provide a few conventions for us, like putting the list in local.settings.php or equivalent. 
I hide per-instance configs in in my site_aliases.drushrc, which is my alternative to local.settings.php

I'm not going for another script you have to call, unless it's part of a fully automated workflow.